# Subtitles in video files

Tags: video, zune-player

I know I can encode subtitles directly in video on my computer. But I don't want to do this every time it's time and space consuming.

But is there any way to upload .SRT and .AVI file on phone and watch it there?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it is not currently possible and you will have to embed the subtitles using a method such as [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1098877).

Comment: I know I can embed them but that is not what I'm asking. Maybe somebody know for an app I'll just wait for answer.

Comment: I know that you mentioned it in your question, I am just confirming that this is currently your only option :)